# HOW to transfer data between 2 services in Microservices that using RabbitMQ in CQRS?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, rabbitmq

In CQRS, there are 3 types: Event, Command, Query
I have readied some example on github. They just config RabbitMQ publisher for 2 types are Event, Command.

Example: Service.A, Service.B
Service A need select some information from Service B base on id.

In CQRS, I'm using Query types, I would like to sent data to Service.B and get result of Service.B.

Can I use rabbitMQ or HTTP client for that?

```
 public async Task PublishAsync<TEvent>(TEvent _event, ICorrelationContext context) where TEvent : IEvent
    {
        var eventName = _event.GetType().Name;
        _logger.LogInformation($"[Published an event] : '{eventName}'");

        await _busClient.PublishAsync(_event, ctx => ctx.UseMessageContext(context)
            .UsePublishConfiguration(p => p.WithRoutingKey(GetRoutingKey(_event))));
    }

 public async Task SendAsync<TCommand>(TCommand command, ICorrelationContext context) where TCommand : ICommand
    {
        var commandName = command.GetType().Name;
        _logger.LogInformation($"[Sent a command] : '{commandName}'"); ;

        await _busClient.PublishAsync(command, ctx => ctx.UseMessageContext(context)
            .UsePublishConfiguration(p => p.WithRoutingKey(GetRoutingKey(command))));   
    }
```